# Which steps are needed to change motherboard on Windows 7 without reinstalling?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade my **Sapphire AM2+ Motherboard** (Chipset **780G**) with a new **MSI AM3** (Chipset **785G**).

**I don't want to format and reinstall Windows 7.**

I have heard that with Windows XP is not that easy because SATA drivers are not available by default, but maybe for Windows 7 things are easier.

Do you know  which steps do I have to follow to achieve my target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chipsets are hopefully close enough that it should work without too much problems.

It worked for me when I replaced the motherboard of my PC, from an Asus P5B-E (chipset P965) to an Asus P5Q-E (chipset P45). Windows 7 (64-bits Ultimate) took some time to identify the new hardware and install the drivers but, after a reboot, it worked flawlessly.

Make sure to have the minimum of external peripherals connected when you restart the PC (except mouse and keyboard), and add them back once at a time after the motherboard devices have been identified and the PC rebooted.

Comment: +1, this sounds good. You could also un-install or disable hardware in Windows before switching the board and avoid other peripherals (like external drives and spare adapters or USB devices) for the first boot to speed it up.

Comment: Did you uninstall some devices before (from device manager) or it wasn't necessary?

Comment: I didn't uninstall anything.

Comment: next week, when MB arrive, I will try and let you know

Comment: done! i did a couple of reboots and Windows 7 detected all changes. Very nice :D